# Mi tabla responssive con bootstrap 4 no se ajusta bien a mi movil

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive, html-tabla

estoy haciendo un **carrito** para verlo desde el movil pero no acab ade verse muy bien, este es el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <title>Carrito</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>


<style> 
    body {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>


<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">


<div class="container">



<!--  shopping-cart-wrap -->
    <div class="card">
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="text-muted">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th scope="col" width="120">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col" width="120">Price</th>
      <th scope="col" width="200" class="text-right">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <figure class="media">

        <figcaption class="media-body">
            <h6 class="title text-truncate">Product name goes here </h6>
        </figcaption>
    </figure> 
        </td>
        <td> 
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>  
                <option>3</option>  
                <option>4</option>                  
                <option>5</option>  
                <option>6</option>  
                <option>7</option>                 
                <option>8</option>  
                <option>9</option>  
                <option>10</option>  
                <option>+ 10</option>  
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div class="price-wrap"> 
                <var class="price">USD 145</var> 
                <small class="text-muted">(USD5 each)</small> 
            </div> <!-- price-wrap .// -->
        </td>
        <td class="text-right"> 
        <a title="" href="" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save to Wishlist"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a> 
        <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-danger"> × Remove</a>
        </td>
    </tr>


    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div> <!-- card.// -->

    </div> 
    <!--container end.//-->

</body>
</html>
```

A continuacion dejo una captura con mi movil de como se ve:

[image: Imagen de la web version movil]

Como os podeis fijar hay un corte con el **border** de la tabla que no lelga hasta el final. Por el lado izquierdo queda bien, pero por la derecha se queda como a medio camino. Y la cosa es que va a ser una web usada por movil siempre. 
**Como podria arreglarlo de forma que el borde llegue hasta el final ?**

Answer (score 0):

Ya me di cuenta que era, la tabla esta dentro de un `<div class="card">`, simplemente se lo he quitado ya se ve perfectamente.

Comment: También puedes usar la clase table-responsive de bootstrap.

Comment: de acuerdo, lo probare. Muchas gracias.